# editor in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I had just installed cygwin on my win XP machine, new to unix & learning things...

1. How can I know which editor had been installed with cygwin installation on my system? none of the editors out of vi, vim, nano, ted, jow etc working...tried using 'notepad' but it saves the file as .txt ....
2. Also another confusion which I have is, even the files which I have created without shebang line as well as without .sh extension , I am able to execute them when given permission to do so...how can a script be run when I have not added shebang line in that?

Answer (score 22):

I had trouble with this and a few other things in Cygwin. Vim, Emacs, (and many other standard Unix programs) are not installed by default in Cygwin.

You need to run the setup program again (no need to uninstall first), and explicitly add what you want.

I wrote a blog post about this: http://wilsonericn.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/cygwin-setup-gotchas/

Comment: Hey thanks, yeps now hv installed vim editor by running set up agn..hv also installed 'mintty ' too bt i quite like standard cygwin window better..thanks fr ur reply

Answer (score 5):

The shebang line is not needed if your $SHELL can interpret the script. i.e., if you write a bash script and invoke it through bash, you don't need the shebang line.

To know which editors are installed, run the cygwin setup.exe file again and go through the package list (under the group editors), you may pick additional editors to install too.

Comment: oh okay, thanks....so i also do not need to add .sh extension to my scripts too? a.) do any file i create & give execute permission will get executed even if it doesn't have both shebang as well as .sh extension?    Also, if i use 'notepad' command an editor opens up & i write my script in that, if i save that it gets saved as .txt file, so that means i should hv been able to run this file since scripts are also text file , so why I am nt able to execute it?

Comment: Thats is correct (for your shell scripts).

Comment: If you create a file in notepad, it saves it as a Windows format text file with CR-LF (`\r\n`) line endings.  Cygwin's default configuration uses Unix format text files, with LF (`\n`) line endings.  I just tried creating a script `bar.sh` using notepad (to avoid the `.txt` extension, change `Save as type:` to `All files (*.*)`); when I tried to run it, I got `./bar.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found`.  There are ways around that, but if you're going to be using Cygwin it's probably better to learn to use one of the editors it provides.

Comment: hey thanks for explaining well...so if that ws the case, bei

Comment: hey thanks for explaining well..so if that was the case,being line endings,so i just wrote a script without shebang line using notepad again to just confirm is it only lineendings,i wrote tht script with only one line 'echo hello world' without shebang too, so that with one line there wont be any issue of line endings & since am using cygwin with only bash shell anyways the script wil be executed..& yes it got executed fine..i ws good tht it was only line endings issue..bt again to confirm I again wrote script without shebang line & 2 lines of code & to my surprise ths script also got executed

Comment: (in continuation of my above comment) if line endings would be the issue this second script with two lines of code wouldn't hv been executed...just to summarise, if I am adding sheband line in that notepad file then its not getting executed( i mean it must be considering line after shebang as without carriage return) bt if am nt using shebang it is executing that notepad file irrespective of how many lines of code is there...:( hope my question is clear :(

Comment: let me know should i write the code of all the three scripts here...pls note, am using cygwin on winXP & used 'notepad' command in cygwin & thus saving that notepad file by mycomputer-> C: -> home -> user   since thtts the only way to save those notepad scripts

Comment: just to add wht all i wrote above, the crux is..notepad is indeed saved with windows line endings & thus cygwin/unix doesn't recognize '\r ' but thts only the case when we add one blank line in code..if we dont hv any blank line in code in notepad..the cript gets executed fine n yes with or without shebang line...the only issue is if we hv blank line of code then only it encounter '\r' otherwise no probs...thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have other scripts, you should be able to launch most scripts without sheband line in this way:

```
bash script.sh
tcsh script.csh
python script.py
perl script.pl
```

etc...

By the way, if you are new to unix, I recommend you get used to an advanced text editor.
I don't want to troll, but using XEmacs or Vim could help you a lot (syntax highlighting, snippet usage for ex.). I have been using Vim for years now, and I would probably not be able to go back to a basic editor...

Comment: Thanks for ur answer! yes i hv now installed vim as editor  & yes its not difficlt but there are sum uncertainties like cursor moves upto first charater of script sumtimes & main thing is am not able to get why,haha, getting used to it

Comment: What is your motion issue? I did not get the point. The best thing to do is getting used to motions with h, j, k, l and w, e, b (E and B are also interesting). Just open a non empty file and give it a try.

Comment: hey thanks, yes am getting used to it...not difficult,just need practise, also i had another question abt cygwin which is:- Is there a way we can see what we have typed above in a cygwin console window, since after i type so many things & then when i go up scrolling am nt able to go up to where i started, i mean scroll stops after a point, so is there a way we can see uptil from where we have started typing since login? I searched on google & saw we hv to make changes in .Xdefaults file, now where is that file?Also i tried to increase buffer size in cygwin console window from properties tab

Answer (score 1):

If you have the disk space I recommend just letting the Cygwin installer have at it and deploy everything .... I am glancing at it every now and then while watching the F1 race. I use a 750GB hybrid flash / spinning disc drive so storage isn't an issue. It is much like the old Red Hat "Kitchen Sink" option with the DVD9 format.

It would be helpful if the Cygwin installer would show the fact it intends to install only 50/2100 packages by default, or if there was a wizard with some useful premix choices (minimal, server, GUI, everything)

Comment: That would install a lot of packages which you will never ever use. Besides occupying disk space, it will pollute your command-line completion with the commands you don't need, making it harder to type the ones you need. And updating Cygwin will take a long time.