# Cygwin absence of almost all packages

Tags: windows, installation, cygwin

Tried to install Cygwin from the [website](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) and when i execute the setup.exe I am not given all the packages, not even editors package. There is [Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034062/editor-in-cygwin) about this where answer explains how to choose packages while installing but I cant see any of them what he pointed out.

I googled for half hour and I am not able to find how to find those packages. Am I missing something here.

**OS: Windows 7**

Please see the screenshot attached. It only has "Misc" package and this doesnt have basic editors like vi [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you chose

```
Install from Local Directory
```

You should be choosing

```
Install from Internet
```